# Build error - Visual Studio 2013 with Update 1

Tags: build, visual-studio-2013

I installed Visual Studio 2013 on a fresh Windows 8 machine.  Then I installed SQL Server 2012.  Then Installed Visual Studio 2013 Update 1.  Then I opened Visual Studio and tried to build three different LightSwitch HTML projects following a tutorial from Beth Massi.  Each time I got "There were build errors."

Then I started a new project and selected Visual C# Console Application.  As the tutorial said, I inserted this code:

```
// A Hello World! program in C#. 
using System;
namespace HelloWorld
{
class Hello
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

I still get "There were build errors."

What should I do?

Comment: What are the errors? What do you see in the error list and output window?

Comment: Error List: 0 Errors 0 Warnings 0 Messages

Comment: Where do you get build errors then if they are not in the Errors Window?  Can you post a picture?